# looping through dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I built a for loop in order to iterate through the csv file (which is a dataframe and I named it df).

This dataframe consists of all relevant director names. The variable u is referring to the rows of the the dataframe and in the next line I insert u in the URL code.

The code is as follows:

```
# replace l_d_list from the original csv file with the next l_d_list into the URL
Ext = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        u = df.iloc[i, 0]
        b = pd.csv_read(f"URL/?direList={u}&includeInteractors=true")
        c = b.reset_index()[['Interactor A', 'Interactor B']]
    except NameError:
        continue
    Ext.append(c)
```

Unfortunately, the loop iterates only once through the csv file.

As a consequence, I only get the interactions of one director instead of all director interactions. I think the failure is that some directors cannot be find in the database. I tried to solve this by using the `except NameError` command.

However, when I just try to see if it iterates through the CSV to print the variables for u, it works fine:

```
# replace l_d_list from the original csv file with the next l_d_list into the URL
Ext = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    u = df.iloc[i,0]
    b = pd.csv_read(f"URL/?direList={u}&includeInteractors=true")
    c = b.reset_index()[['Interactor A', 'Interactor B']]
    print(u)
    Ext.append(c)
```

Could you tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your indentation is wonky in the top example so it's not possible to see what is inside the loop. Please fix it.

Comment: Also `u == df.iloc[i,0]` is probably supposed to be `u = df.iloc[i,0]`

Comment: Fstring in second example is missing closing double quote.  This is why the next lines appear red.